# Uri en ImageView , no carga al cerrar aplicacion

Tags: java, android

Actualmente en mi aplicación Android , tengo en mi menu ,la posibilidad de guardar una imagen , para ello tengo un formulario donde le pido al usuario que elija una de su telefono con el siguiente codigo

Codigo :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
        // imageUri = data.getData();
        //foto_gallery.setImageURI(imageUri);
        //foto_gallery.setBackground(null);
        imageUri = data.getData();
        foto_gallery.setImageURI(imageUri);
        foto_gallery.setBackground(null);
        foto_gallery.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bmap = foto_gallery.getDrawingCache();
        //creamos el drawable redondeado
        RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedDrawable =
                RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), bmap);
        //asignamos el CornerRadius
        roundedDrawable.setCornerRadius(bmap.getHeight());
        roundedDrawable.setCircular(true);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.foto_gallery);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(roundedDrawable);
        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
        if (db != null) {
            ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
            value.put("IMAGENURL", imageUri.toString());
            db.saveImagen(value);

        }
```

lo que hace esto es elegir la imagen , hace un "Intento de dejarla redonda " y procede a guardarla en sqlLITe , hasta aca todo bien , muestra la imagen correctamente en el menu etc ,  lo que guardo en SQL LITE es la URI de la imgen en este caso que recien probe guarda

> ```
>     content://media/external/images/media/15525
> ```

Ahora cuando cierro la aplicacion y la vuelvo abrir , llamo a recuperar imagen y sastifactoriamente me trae la misma uri

> ```
>     content://media/external/images/media/15525
> ```

pero a la hora de ver la imagen la misma viene vacia , me gustaria saber porque podría ser que no aparezca la imagen si anteriormente si aparece , y es la misma uri ,

este es el codigo en la master donde llama al recuperar y setea la imagen

```
 public void MenuConfiguracion() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.bringToFront();
    drawer.requestLayout();
    final ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.bringToFront();
    navigationView.requestLayout();




    ImageView profile = (ImageView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.foto_gallery);
    String auxruta = this.cargarFotoPerfil();

    Uri myUri = Uri.parse(auxruta);
    profile.setImageURI(myUri);
}

 public String cargarFotoPerfil(){
    String auxUri= "";
    DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
    if (db != null) {
        Cursor auxCursor = db.recuperarImagen();
        auxCursor.moveToFirst();

        while (!auxCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            if(auxCursor.getString(auxCursor.getColumnIndex("IMAGENURL"))!=null){
                auxUri = auxCursor.getString(auxCursor.getColumnIndex("IMAGENURL"));

            }
            auxCursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return auxUri;
}
```

este es el logCAT

Unable to open content: content://media/external/images/media/15525

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri
>   content://media/external/images/media/15525 from pid=14438, uid=10188
>   requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or
>   grantUriPermission()
>                                                                                     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)

Comment: Hola Bruno, trata siempre de agregar los mensajes de error que se despliegan en el LogCat-

Comment: Jorge a mi me parece que no tira errores , pero dejame chequear !

Comment: Si tenias razon si tira errores que tonto de mi parte

Comment: requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: En este caso estas usando un  contentprovider y cargando la imagen mediante su URI, estuve buscando si había  alguna que hiciera referencia a permisos, creo que sería util

Comment: esto ultimo si me perdi..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es importante el uso del LogCat para determinar rápidamente los errores, en este caso:

> requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or
>   grantUriPermission()
>                                                                                 at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)

**En realidad no esta pudiendo guardar la imagen, por eso cuando regresas no encuentras la imagen.**

Debes declarar el permiso agregando directamente a tu AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Pero para android [Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) o posterior el permiso [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) (que implicitamente es tambien `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` se debe requerir manualmente, llama este método:

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
}
```

Puedes validar llamar el metodo unicamente el sistemas operativos mayores o igual a Android 6.0 :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    //Verifica permisos para Android 6.0+
     checkExternalStoragePermission();
}
```