# ¿Como puedo adjuntar pdf en correo para api 29?

Tags: android

¿Como puedo adjuntar pdf en correo para api 29?

este es mi código, pero no funciona con mi huawei android 9.1

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/Pdf_Ordenes/",Cliente + spinnumero + ".pdf" ));
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,recipiente);
intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subject);
intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_TEXT,mensajeTotal);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Seleccione el metodo de mensajeria"));
```

Comment: ¿Has revisado el LogCat que error se muestra al tratar de realizar el intent?

Answer (score 0):

Tu código debe funcionar sin problema, solo necesitas asegurar 2 cosas:

• **Tu aplicación debe tener definido el permios `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, tanto en el `AndroidManifest.xml` como requerirlo manualmente.**

[Declarar y definir permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115196/uri-en-imageview-no-carga-al-cerrar-aplicacion/115212#115212)

**• La ruta que defines para el pdf debe ser correcta y el archivo debe existir**, te sugiero revisar la ruta que define el lugar donde se encuentra el .pdf:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/Pdf_Ordenes/",Cliente + spinnumero + ".pdf"
```

Comment: gracias, lo corregi con esto: StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
                                                    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

Comment: Eso no tiene que ver con la pregunta, es para permitir operaciones en el hilo principal, lo cual no es recomendable, si estoy soluciono el problema entonces tenias un problema en otro punto de la aplicación.